# Major lag (3 seconds) when hiding check box

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a fancy checkbox, its not that fancy to cause this much lag but im trying to make it dissaper.

I do this by making its parent div dissaper which does so instantly but leaves the checkbox there for about 3 seconds.

Heres the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zpun567w/16/

I have to accompany it by code so heres how im making it dissapere:

```
document.getElementById("clickHide").addEventListener('click', function (){

document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = 'hidden'; 

});
```

Also just to clarify this is part of a bigger project so im not looking for ways to make the individual checkbox dissapere by setting the display to none. It needs to be visibility and prefrably the whole div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not 3 seconds for me, but you have `transition: .4s` set on your elements. Naturally you want the slider to still be animated. To do this, set *which* properties you'd like to transition, as the default is to transition *all* of them (not what you want).

Doing that, you'll get the result you expect.

Here's the updated code.

```js
document.getElementById("clickHide").addEventListener('click', function (){
  document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color:red;
}
.switch input {
  display:none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .4s; /* we're transitioning `background-color` here */
  transition: background-color .4s; /* and this */
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: transform .4s; /* we're transitioning `transform` here */
  transition: transform .4s; /* and here */
  border-radius: 50px;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hide">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>

<button id="clickHide">
  click me
</button>
```

Comment: ah of course! i didnt even think about that, well spotted, thankyou